Collection of finite unions of open sets always has a cofinal chain?
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a top space, and $\mathcal{O}:=\{U_i\in \tau: i\in I\}$ a collection of open sets with index set $I$.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of finite subsets of $I$, and
$$\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{F}:=\left\{U_{i_1}\cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n}: \{i_1,\cdots, i_n\}\in \mathcal{F} \text{ and every }U_{i_k}\in \mathcal{O}\right\}$$
is the collection of all finite unions of open sets in $\mathcal{O}$, partially ordered by set inclusion. Does $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{F}$ always admit a cofinal chain?

I know, in general, $\mathcal{F}$ does not have a cofinal chain. But my question is about $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{F}$. If equipping $\mathcal{F}$ with a well-order, disregarding the set-inclusion order, then sets in $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{F}$ is indexed by a well-ordered chain. Can we conclude there is an increasing chain that is cofinal from this? Thanks in advance.

It seems hard to me if $I$ is uncountable.

Take an uncountable discrete topological space $X$, $I=X$ and $U_i={i}$. Then the maximal chains in $\mathcal O_{\mathcal F}$ are order-isomorphic to $\omega$: in a chain $C$, take a subset of minimal cardinality, which must be unique because they're all finite and one is a subset of the other, then a (actually, the) subset of minimal cardinality that isn't the former and so on; the map $(C,\subseteq)\mapsto (\Bbb N,\le)$, $x\mapsto \lvert x\rvert$ is stricly increasing. So there is some $i\in X\setminus\bigcup C$, and $U_i$ is not comparable to the elements of $C$.

@SassatelliGiulio So any $I$ whose $\mathcal{F}$ doesn't have a cofinal chain is a counterexample. We just need to equip $I$ with the discrete topology, and $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}$.

@user760 I am deliberately ignoring the whole "order other than set inclusion" thing.
